# Target does not exist error building an Ant project for a Cordova app on OS X

Tags: android, macos, cordova, ant

When I try to build a phonegap/cordova app with command:

```
cordova build android
```

I'm getting an error:

```
BUILD FAILED
Target "debug" does not exist in the project "CordovaApp". 

Total time: 0 seconds

/path_to_app/platforms/android/cordova/node_modules/q/q.js:126
                    throw e;
                          ^
Error code 1 for command: ant with args: debug,-f,/path_to_app/platforms/android/build.xml,-Dout.dir=ant-build,-Dgen.absolute.dir=ant-gen
ERROR building one of the platforms: Error: /path_to_app/platforms/android/cordova/build: Command failed with exit code 8
You may not have the required environment or OS to build this project
```

I think it can be related with my `~/Library/Android/sdk/tools/ant/build.xml` file - I maybe accidentally mess it up - could anyone provide me code from that file?

Please help.

Answer (score 1):

The Ant build is failing with this error message:

> Target "debug" does not exist in the project "CordovaApp".

The following part of the error message shows that something is trying to run the `debug` target of Ant:

> Error code 1 for command: ant with args: **debug**,-f,/path_to_app/platforms/android/build.xml

The file `/path_to_app/platforms/android/build.xml` likely doesn't have a target named `debug`. This is why Ant fails. You will need to determine what is launching the Ant script and why the launcher expects the `build.xml` file to have a `debug` target.